# Wordcount ran on Tachyon showing ClassNotFoundException Exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, alluxio

I am trying to run Hadoop Wordcount on Tachyon. I followed this [link](http://tachyon-project.org/documentation/Running-Hadoop-MapReduce-on-Tachyon.html).
But once I run wordcount Jar with below command

```
hadoop jar HadoopWordCount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.WordCount -libjars tachyon-client-0.7.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar tachyon://tachyon_ip:19998/wordcountsample/word2.txtaa /OUT/wcTachyon
```

I am getting below error.

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class tachyon.hadoop.TFS not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
```

I am new to Tachyon.

Please advice.

Comment: tachyon-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar should also be used.

Comment: along with tachyon-client-0.7.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar do we need to add tachyon-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar also?